# how to make spectrum color button/ color picker button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to build a button that will display color spectrum onclick, and by clicking on a spot inside the color spectum, the spot color will be picked and the text color will change according to the picked color.

This is kind of what I need

[image]

Thanks in advance

p.s
Spectrum color area need to accessible with keyboard as well.

Comment: Where’s your attempt?

Comment: creating a color apectrum button that the text will change according to its color

Comment: I’m not sure what you’re referring to in your comments. You seem to rephrase your request. But as far as we don’t see any _attempt_ (i.e. _code of your own_), most of us aren’t interested in answering this question.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/7432

Comment: @Xufox I don't have any code, this is why I am here, but if you really need 1 so:  
`jQuery('#foo').on('click', function()  
{ //get the color and copy the color hex id (or rgb) from spectrum to varible })`

Answer (score 4):

This is a basic outline of what you would need. To get smoother colors lower the value that `i` increases by and the `width` of the `divs` (You'll have to do some math). Hope this helps :).

```js
function getColor(){
  style = window.getComputedStyle(this),
  bgColor = style.getPropertyValue('background-color');
  document.querySelector('h1').style.color = bgColor;
}
var cont = document.getElementById('cont');
for(i=0; i<350; i=i+14){
  var div=document.createElement('div');
  cont.appendChild(div);
  div.style.background = 'hsl(' + i + ',100%, 50%)';
  div.addEventListener('click', getColor);
}
```

```css
@import url('https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/latest/normalize.css');
#cont{ border:1px solid black; width:200px; height:30px; }
#cont div{ 
  width:4%; height:100%; float:left;
}
```

```html
<div id="cont">
</div>
<h1>text</h1>
```

Comment: Maybe I'm blind, but I don't see where or how this posts a color picker that looks like a spectrum.    The easiest way to implement a spectrum is the way I did many years ago: I consulted the horseshoe-shaped CIE television chromaticity diagram and digitized however many breakpoints.  I then linearly segued from one breakpoint to the next.  The result was a facile mockup of your standard VIBGYOR (or Roy G. Biv: it depends what freshman physics text you used) paradigm.

Comment: @BruceDavidWilner As said in the original post simple adjustments of `i` and the `div` width can output a more *'spectrumy'* result: https://jsfiddle.net/Lo5eky9m/